# TabLayout properties are not available in my library

Tags: android, gradle

I made a library in which I am using AndroidX, also I used a TabLayout in the layout file which has properties like `app:tabBackground`,`app:tabGravity`, `app:tabIndicatorHeight`, `app:tabMaxWidth` etc.

For using this TabLayout I included this dependency

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha02'
```

which was earlier in this dependency (before AndroidX)

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

Now when I package this library using JCenter and including the library in some other project, it shows error

> Android resource linking failed

for the four above mentioned properties of the material TabLayout, now when I explicitly include the TabLayout dependency in my test project, the error gets resolved and all work as expected. But shouldn't that work without the need to explicitly include the library when I have actually included the same dependency in my library's `build.gradle` file. Can anyone help me fixing this?

My library's build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'
group = 'com.github.technolifestyle'

ext {
    bintrayRepo = 'AutoImageFlipper'
    bintrayName = 'AutoImageFlipper'

    publishedGroupId = 'com.github.technolifestyle'
    libraryName = 'AutoImageFlipper'
    artifact = 'imageslider'

    libraryDescription = 'A carousel like implementation for Android with many functionalities'

    siteUrl = 'https://github.com/therealshabi/AutoImageFlipper/'
    gitUrl = 'https://github.com/therealshabi/AutoImageFlipper.git'

    libraryVersion = '1.5.6'

    developerId = 'therealshabi'
    developerName = 'Shahbaz Hussain'
    developerEmail = 'shahbaz.h96@gmail.com'

    licenseName = 'The Apache Software License, Version 2.0'
    licenseUrl = 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt'
    allLicenses = ["Apache-2.0"]
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            useProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    api fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha02'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation files('libs/picasso-2.5.2.jar')
}

apply from: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nuuneoi/JCenter/master/installv1.gradle'
apply from: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nuuneoi/JCenter/master/bintrayv1.gradle'
```

My app's build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.shahbaz.testapplication"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {

        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha3'
    api 'com.github.technolifestyle:imageslider:1.5.6'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}
```

My logcat error:

```
Android resource linking failed
/Users/therealshabi/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/imageslider-1.5.6.aar/7613a0787048f4fcec061a14a3d7277f/res/layout/flipper_layout.xml:15: error: attribute tabBackground (aka technolifestyle.com.kotlin_practice:tabBackground) not found.
/Users/therealshabi/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/imageslider-1.5.6.aar/7613a0787048f4fcec061a14a3d7277f/res/layout/flipper_layout.xml:15: error: attribute tabGravity (aka technolifestyle.com.kotlin_practice:tabGravity) not found.
/Users/therealshabi/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/imageslider-1.5.6.aar/7613a0787048f4fcec061a14a3d7277f/res/layout/flipper_layout.xml:15: error: attribute tabIndicatorHeight (aka technolifestyle.com.kotlin_practice:tabIndicatorHeight) not found.
/Users/therealshabi/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/imageslider-1.5.6.aar/7613a0787048f4fcec061a14a3d7277f/res/layout/flipper_layout.xml:15: error: attribute tabMaxWidth (aka technolifestyle.com.kotlin_practice:tabMaxWidth) not found.
```

Comment: Try property `android.enableJetifier=true` in **gradle.properties** file in your project where you include your library.

Comment: @JeelVankhede Actually I have already migrated my test project to AndroidX, coz apparently a library made using AndroidX won't work in a non-AndroidX project, So I had to migrate my test project, and hence `android.enableJetifier = true` is already there in my **gradle.properties**

Comment: Try with transitive property : `api ('com.github.technolifestyle:imageslider:1.5.6') {
       transitive=true
}`

Comment: @JeelVankhede Still the same

Comment: One more thing, why do you use `api` attribute instead of `implementation` if you're compiling your dependencies?

Comment: I actually tried to use `implementation` first, but since it gave me the error, I tried the `api` too which is apparently the same as `compile` used before. In this case, it doesn't matter what I am using, both will give the same result. Hence the error persisted even with the `api` statement

Comment: Please share complete logcat error.

Comment: @JeelVankhede added logcat output